# Find maximum and minimum double value in a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have the following list of double values:

```
items {9.0, 4.0, 16.0, -6.0, 5.0}
```

I want to find the maximum and minimum values and for that I did:

```
double max = items.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(String::valueOf)).get();
double min = items.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(String::valueOf)).get();
```

The result that I got is `max=9.0` and `min=-6.0`. I was expecting the maximum to be `16.0`. Later, I changed `16.0` to `92.0` and it worked; it gave me `max=92.0`

Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: The problem is that you're comparing strings and `9xx` is always greater than `1xxx`.

Comment: You want to use `Double::valueOf`, not `String::valueOf`.

Answer (score 12):

You don't want to compare using strings but by the natural order of your double elements, i.e. `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `Comparator.comparing(String::valueOf)`.

Comparing via strings will result in the characters being compared and since the character value of `9` (of `"9.0"`) is greater than `1` (of `"16.0"`) you get the result you see. Changing `"16.0"` to `"92.0"` will result in `.` to be compared with `2` (since the first character is equal) and thus `"92xx"` is greater than `"9.xx"`.

Answer (score 12):

What about :

```
double max = items.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).max().getAsDouble();//16.0
double min = items.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).min().getAsDouble();//-6.0
```

Comment: This answers the exact question +1.

Answer (score 7):

It appears you want to compare the number numerically instead of their String representation e.g. `"16.0" < "9.0"` as `'1' < '9'`

```
List<Double> items = Arrays.asList(9.0, 4.0, 16.0, -6.0, 5.0);
double max = items.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
double min = items.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
System.out.println(min + " " + max);
```

prints

```
-6.0 16.0
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a more appropriate stream type for doubles. Using it, you can get `min` and `max` in one terminal operation (eliminating the need to supply a comparator in the process):

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = items.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d)
 .summaryStatistics();
//even better: DoubleStream.of(9.0, 4.0, 16.0, -6.0, 5.0).summaryStatistics()
```

And `stats` will have:

```
count=5, sum=28.000000, min=-6.000000, average=5.600000, max=16.000000
```

Comment: good, the nitpick would be that this does a bit more than just min and max - but yes, totally agreed on this solution

Answer (score 4):

Your are comparing them as `String` so by alphabetical order : 1xx is before 9xx

You need to compare then as `Double or Integer`, so use `Comparator.comparing(Double::valueOf)` (or `Integer::valueOf`)

Answer (score -1):

items
.stream()
.sorted()
.limit(1)
.collect(Colletors.toList();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).